# Why does `htop` show more process than `ps`

Tags: process, ps, top, htop, thread

In `ps xf`

```
26395 pts/78   Ss     0:00  \_ bash
27016 pts/78   Sl+    0:04  |   \_ unicorn_rails master -c config/unicorn.rb                                           
27042 pts/78   Sl+    0:00  |       \_ unicorn_rails worker[0] -c config/unicorn.rb
```

In `htop`, it shows up like:
[image: htop showing multiple unicorn_rails lines]

Why does htop show more process than ps?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/118086/why-are-there-many-processes-listed-under-the-same-title-in-htop | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017597/htop-showing-multiple-java-processes-with-different-pids | http://askubuntu.com/questions/17047/in-htop-i-sometimes-see-lists-of-64-processes-identical-for-all-but-the-pid-w

Answer (score 364, accepted):

By default, `htop` lists each thread of a process separately, while `ps` doesn't. To turn off the display of threads, press `H`, or use the "Setup / Display options" menu, "Hide userland threads". This puts the following line in your `~/.htoprc` or `~/.config/htop/htoprc` (you can alternatively put it there manually):

```
hide_userland_threads=1
```

(Also `hide_kernel_threads=1`, toggled by pressing `K`, but it's 1 by default.)

Another useful option is “Display threads in a different color” in the same menu (`highlight_threads=1` in `.htoprc`), which causes threads to be shown in a different color (green in the default theme).

In the first line of the `htop` display, there's a line like “Tasks: 377, 842 thr, 161 kthr; 2 running”. This shows the total number of processes, userland threads, kernel threads, and threads in a runnable state. The numbers don't change when you filter the display, but the indications “thr” and “kthr” disappear when you turn off the inclusion of user/kernel threads respectively.

When you see multiple processes that have all characteristics in common except the PID and CPU-related fields (NIce value, CPU%, TIME+, ...), it's highly likely that they're threads in the same process.

Comment: Any clue about why this is the default? Why is that relevant? It seems like adding noise but I guess there is a good reason.

Comment: @tuxayo I was curious too and found this: https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/99#issuecomment-748142128 tl;dr it was a kind of a philosophical choice.

Answer (score 4):

For me, on a more-or-less current arch linux system, `ps xf` shows me only the processes owned by my user ID.  `htop` shows me all processes.  Try `ps -ef` for a list of all processes, or perhaps `ps -ejH` to get a child/parent relationship listing.

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. However I was hoping to get the tree structure within `htop`.

Comment: Pressing F5 switches to tree view

Answer (score 0):

htop is also showing processes that have ended. This is great, so you can see short-lived processes and what resources they might have consumed.  If you exit htop and restart it, you'll see they have disappeared. I can't figure out a way to make htop drop historical processes without restarting, so maybe there's a way.