# Why does my one instance of VLC have many processes?

Tags: process, vlc

As you can see from the image below (htop), I have several `vlc` processes running, all with only the command `vlc`. However, I'm only running one vlc instance.

[image]

What are the other instances? Would it be safe to terminate them? And how can I tell which process is attached to my current instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does `htop` show more process than `ps`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those aren't separate processes, they're [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)). VLC has a lot of things going on under the covers, each handled by a separate thread.

Press <kbd>H</kbd> in `htop` to hide threads, showing processes only.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that VLC is spawning child processes (much as the Apache HTTP server does, for example). If that's the case, and if your version of `ps` supports it, you can try running `ps -H` to see processes listed in a tree arrangement. Use `-C vlc` to limit output to only vlc processes.

```
$ ps -H -C apache2
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1374 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 1377 ?        00:00:00   apache2
 1378 ?        00:00:00   apache2
 1379 ?        00:00:00   apache2
```

Alternatively, use `ps -f` to get "full" output, including parent PID (PPID). Again, this makes it clear which process is the parent process.

```
$ ps -f -C apache2
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1374     1  0 03:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1377  1374  0 03:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1378  1374  0 03:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1379  1374  0 03:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```