# How to display `top` results sorted by memory usage in real time?

Tags: terminal, memory, top

How can I display the `top` results in my terminal in real time so that the list is sorted by memory usage?

Comment: On Linux, `>` and `<` move the sort column right and left. Since the `%MEM` column is just right of the `%CPU` column, which is also the default sort column, it takes only one keystroke to switch between the two. I know, your question has the macintosh tag, that's why I'm writing this answer as a comment.

Comment: I prefer `htop`, mainly because it tells me how to do this.

Comment: If using `htop`, in addition to `shift + M`, you will likely want to turn off the display of threads and just show the main process memory consumption with `shift + H`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10403/27902.

Answer (score 664):

#### Use the `top` command in Linux/Unix:

```
top
```

- press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> after running the `top` command
- or you can interactively choose which column to sort on

  - press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to enter the interactive menu
  - press the <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> arrow until the `%MEM` choice is highlighted
  - press <kbd>s</kbd> to select `%MEM` choice
  - press <kbd>enter</kbd> to save your selection
  - press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit the interactive menu

Or specify the sort order on the command line

```
# on OS-X
top -o MEM
# other distros
top -o %MEM
```

#### References

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802481/how-to-see-top-processes-by-actual-memory-usage

Comment: On Linux it's `top -o %MEM` (note the "%")

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq It must depend upon your distribution of Linux, and the package bundled with it. Debian 7 uses `procps-ng` and there is no `-o` option at all in that version. `SHIFT-M` works for me once `top` is launched.

Comment: `top -o %MEM` works on my debian 8 and 9, but not on debian 7, you are right @Christopher Schultz.

Comment: instead of <key>enter</key> it should be <key>q</key>

Comment: "Press Shift + m" is a long-winded way of saying "type M".

Comment: use `top -O` to get a list of the field names which could be used for that -o argument

Comment: this doesn't work for me. shift+m makes nothing

Answer (score 122):

The command line option `-o` (o standing for "Override-sort-field") also works on my Xubuntu machine and according to [the Mac man page of top](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html) it should work on a Macintosh too. If I want to short by memory usage I usually use

```
top -o %MEM
```

which sorts by the column `%MEM`. But I can use `VIRT`, `RES` or `SHR` too. On a Macintosh I would probably use `mem` or `vsize`.

I don't know why or how but this is pretty much different between Unix systems and even between Linux distributions. For example `-o` isn't even available on my Raspberry running Wheezy. It may be worth give it a try though.

Comment: The answer could user more clarity: `%MEM` is given as an answer to the eager reader; while it doesn't work everywhere (by far).

Comment: For Macbook 2014 this is saying: `top -o %MEM
invalid argument -o: %MEM`

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually worked on centos for me.

Comment: Works on Debian 8

Comment: @anon58192932 you should replace `%MEM` (or `PID`, `VIRT`, etc.) by any column name that you see when running `top` only. As noted by *ytg*, "on a Macintosh I would probably use `mem` or `vsize`".

Comment: or `cpu` from mac's top -h: `[-o <key>] [-O <secondaryKey>]
   keys: pid (default), command, cpu, cpu_me, cpu_others, csw,
    time, threads, ports, mregion, mem, rprvt, purg, vsize, vprvt,
    kprvt, kshrd, pgrp, ppid, state, uid, wq, faults, cow, user,
    msgsent, msgrecv, sysbsd, sysmach, pageins, boosts, instrs, cycles`

Comment: +1 to the preceding comment. On my Mac (10.13.6), `top -o '%CPU'` did _not_ work, notwithstanding that "%CPU" is how the column header appears. `top -o CPU` worked fine, as did `top -o cpu`.

Comment: Yep, just do `top -o MEM` since "MEM" is on the list.

Comment: use `top -O` to get a list of the field names which could be used for that -o argument

Comment: [top isn't a POSIX utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html). Even POSIX utilities still only have a few standard options, but implementations will introduce their own extensions. Don't you see BSD `find` being vastly different from GNU `find` or busybox `find`? Depending on which userspace tool the distro uses you'll have different syntax

Answer (score 25):

For Ubuntu 14.04 starting with

```
htop -s PERCENT_MEM
```

or (equivalently)

```
htop --sort-key PERCENT_MEM
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: Works well for OSX as well.

Comment: it's different command. Looking for answer about the `top` command (as asked in this question) not `htop`.

Comment: `htop` is obviously a completely different tool in a different package. In lots of cases you have no choice but `top` because there's no `htop` to install

Answer (score 15):

It seems like the **-o** flag will take the actual column name. So if the top command shows only "mem" then the command should be **"top *-o mem*"**.

For the ubuntu machine I am testing with, the column is called **"%MEM"**. On the OSX Yosemite I tried, it is **"mem"**.

Comment: use `top -O` to get a list of the field names which could be used for that -o argument

Answer (score 8):

The original question seems to have been for a Mac, but for anyone else stumbling across this answer, on Red Hat Linux (and many others), 'top -m' starts top with results sorted by memory usage.

Comment: Not on Debian 8

Comment: Worked on: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (none of the other answers worked).

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the `top` that comes with Ubuntu (`top -v` = `procps-ng version 3.3.10`), then you can use these interactive keyboard shortcuts to change the sorting. Note that these are all capital letters, so either use `shift` or `caps lock`.

`M` %MEM
`N` PID
`P` %CPU
`T` TIME+

By default, they will be sorted in DESC order. Use `R` to toggle ASC/DESC.

To set the sorting from the command line option, use `top -o %MEM`. You can specify any column.

Answer (score 7):

If `top` is already running, press <kbd>o</kbd> . Above the data, a prompt will appear:

```
primary key [xxxxx]:
```

Where `xxxxx` is the current sorting key. Type the name of the column by which you want to sort. If a column name contains "%" or "#", omit the character. For %CPU, just type "cpu".

Answer (score 7):

On linux, run:

```
$ top
```

Then press, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 14.04 - this works just fine:

```
htop --sort-key=PERCENT_MEM
```

Comment: htop is not top

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL 7 & 8, after running `top` I just type `>` to move across columns to sort by.

Since it starts sorted by CPU, only one `>` is required.

[A commenter on the original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128953/how-to-display-top-results-sorted-by-memory-usage-in-real-time/764797#comment393941_128953) has also suggested this.