# Log if Process takes more than X Amount of Ram

Tags: process, ram, logs

I own a root server and I would like to **log**, if any process **uses more than X-amount of Ram**.

Does anyone know a good script or an existing program for that?

Comment: What Unix is this server running?

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct ways for that. But you can script easily a nagios plugin for that (but not only for nagios, also for any system monitoring and alarming software what you are using).

If you don't use any, you can make a cron script for that, too.

For the command line to show processes using the most memory, check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166559/52236) answer.